# ¿Cómo hacer que un TextView se muestre unos segundos después de otro?

Tags: android, textview

lo del titulo, me gustaría saber como hacer para que un textview se vea unos segundos después de mostrar el primero.

Ejemplo: Tengo 2 textview: **tv1 y tv2**. El **tv1** dirá "Hola", y luego quiero que en un lapso de 5 segundos aparezca el otro textview (**tv2**) diciendo "Bienvenido" ¿cómo configuro para que después de 5 segundos se vea el **tv2** y no que aparezcan los 2 textview al mismo tiempo? Un saludo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo utilizaría el mismo textView que cambie el texto con un timer una vez transcurridos los 5 segundos.

```
TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
      
    new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
    
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {  
            tv1.setText("HOLA");
                   
        }
    
        public void onFinish() {
        
            tv1.setText("BIENVENIDO");
        }
    
    }.start();
```

Pero si lo que necesitas son 2 textView diferentes prueba con las propiedades visible ocultando el primer textView  y mostrando el segundo textView cuando pasen los 5 segundos, encontrándose este invisible inicialmente.

```
TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
TextView tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
     
    new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
    
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {  
            tv1.setText("HOLA");
                   
        }
    
        public void onFinish() {
            tv1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            tv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tv2.setText("BIENVENIDO");
        }
    
    }.start();
```

Para ocultar el textView puedes hacerlo de dos maneras:

> View.INVISIBLE : esta vista es invisible pero ocupa espacio para fines de diseño

> View.GONE : esta vista es invisible y no ocupa espacio para el diseño